# How to convert pandas dataframe to pyspark dataframe which has attribute to rdd?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark

Now I am doing a project for my course, and find a problem to convert `pandas dataframe` to `pyspark dataframe` .
I have produce a pandas dataframe named data_org as follows.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yfjml.png)

And I want to covert it into pyspark dataframe to adjust it into libsvm format.
So my code is

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext  
spark_df = SQLContext.createDataFrame(data_org)
```

However, it went wrong.

> TypeError: createDataFrame() missing 1 required positional argument: 'data'

I really do not know how to do. And my python version is 3.5.2 and pyspark version is 2.0.1.
I am looking forward to your reply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First pass sparkContext to SQLContext:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext 
sc = SparkContext("local", "App Name")
sql = SQLContext(sc)
```

then use `createDataFrame` like below:

```
spark_df = sql.createDataFrame(data_org)
```

Comment: what does sc mean? I fisrt attain my data by the format of pandas dataframe.

Comment: sc means sparkContext. if you are running the script using spark-submit, it is initialized by spark

Comment: I use the anaconda spyder to run to pyspark code. How to solve the problem in this situation?

Comment: Thanks a million !

Comment: Can you help me solve my another question?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49559331/how-to-deal-with-the-py4jjavaerror-when-i-use-the-pyspark-to-produce-the-libsvm

Comment: Unfortunately, when i run the code again (sc = SparkContext("local", "App Name")
), it went wrong. Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.

Comment: Hey All, How do we convert a pandas df into a spark df inside a UDF, I get SPARK-5063 error when I try spark.createDataFrame(query_result)